# How can I tell if the contextmenu item was clicked with the mouse or fired by a hotkey?

Tags: c#, winforms, hotkeys

I have a `DataGridView` with a context menu.  One menu item is Copy (with a Ctrl+C hotkey.)  All I want to do is either get the current mouse location to copy the cell that the user right-clicked, or get the currently selected cell if they used the hot-key.  In both cases the `menu_Click` event gets fired.  How can I tell if it was from a hotkey or the context menu?

Comment: doesn't right-clicking on a cell select that cell? If not, I would try to get that to work ,as copying something that is not selected may confuse users.

Comment: Have a look at [RoutedEventArgs.Source Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.source.aspx).

Comment: No, the cell is not selected from a right click, but a few line of code later and it is!  Simple solutions are always the best.  Thanks for everyone's help.  Can I vote for a comment?

Answer (score 1):

To best of my knowledge you can `Hook` all the `Mouse` and `Keyboard` events to detect the source of input.

You should have a look at this *CodeProject* article, [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CSLLKeyboard.aspx)

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A *global hook* monitors messages for all threads in the same desktop as the calling thread. A *thread-specific hook* monitors messages for only an individual thread. A global hook procedure can be called in the context of any application in the same desktop as the calling thread, so the procedure must be in a separate DLL module. A thread-specific hook procedure is called only in the context of the associated thread.